# ACF get_field not returning value

Tags: wordpress, loops, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to use get_field to return a simple text field and it returns empty for some reason. A field itself is where it should be and there is text in it, so that part is all set. This PHP code is loaded via php snippet, post thumbnail for example, shows up perfectly. So everything works except for ACF field value.

```php
<div class="your-class">
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'home_test',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby'   => 'name',
        'order'     => 'ASC',
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
    $brand = get_posts($args);
    foreach ($brand as $post) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'full');

        $homelinkvalue = get_field("home_brand_link");

        if (!$thumbnail)
            continue;
        ?>
        <div>
            <p><?php echo $homelinkvalue; ?></p><img src="<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>">
        </div>

    <?php
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are mixing together a custom post loop (your `foreach` and `setup_postdata()`) but then are using functions like `get_field()`, which make use of the **global** post object. In this case, `get_field()` tries to lookup the field value by checking against the global `$post`, but it has not been properly set. See warning [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata) about `setup_postdata($post)`:

> You **must** pass a reference to the global $post variable, otherwise functions like the_title() don't work properly.

You can implement this in your code with a slight modification:

```php
global $post;
foreach ($brand as $currPost) {
    $post = $currPost;
    setup_postdata($post);
    // Rest of code as normal
}
```

Or, since [`get_field()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) can accept a specific post as an argument instead of automatically using the global one, you could change:

```php
$homelinkvalue = get_field("home_brand_link");
```

to:

```php
$homelinkvalue = get_field("home_brand_link",$post->ID);
```

---

Side note: Normally, the recommended way to iterate posts is with the [special "WP loop" pattern](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), something like:

```php
<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <!-- Do something -->
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Using the above pattern automatically sets the global `$post` variable as it loops through, which allows devs to use functions like `get_field()` without having to worry about explicitly passing in a specific post; makes things a bit easier.

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed it! (the first suggestion to add a global variable!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<div class="your-class">
       <?php
          $args = array(
                          'post_type' => 'home_test',
                          'posts_per_page' => -1,
                          'orderby'   => 'name',
                          'order'     => 'ASC',
          );
          $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
          if ($the_query->have_posts) :
              while($the_query->have_posts) : $the_query->the_post();
          ?>
       <div>
          <p><?php the_field( "home_brand_link" ); ?></p>
          <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>">
       </div>
       <?php
          endwhile;
          wp_reset_postdata();
          endif;
          ?>
    </div>
```